# com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Expected an int

Tags: java, json, gson

I am attempting to parse a JSON response but I am getting `NumberFormatException` on the following JSON response

```
"amount": 5.99
```

I am using Google Gson to parse the json into java object

```java
@SerializedName("amount")
private Double amount;

public Double getAmount() {
    return amount;
}

public void setAmount(Double amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}
```

```java
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
Response response = gson.fromJson(json, Response.class);
```

The value from the response is given as a double but the error states "Expected an int but was 5.99"  I have tried changing the data type to an `Integer` or `String` but still throwing the `NumberFormatException`.

Any way around this?

Comment: Can you post a [mcve], the Double should work

Comment: You're definitely doing something wrong. It should work (assuming you have curly braces in the givenn JSON). I suspect, you have wrong assumptions on this field, and another field causes your issue.

Comment: Please post the entire JSON Response and the POJO

Answer (score 0):

The problem is 5.99 is neither an Integer nor a string, it can be a double or a float

Comment: change it to be a float or double